# Rails IF --- IN syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to limit a portion of my site based on usernames.

I'm trying to insert a command like the below but I get a syntax error.

```
if current_user.name in ("user1", "user2", "user3")
```

I also tried the below. This didn't work in limiting access to the specified usernames but I didn't get any errors.

```
if current_user.name == "user1" || "user2" || "user3"
```

How should I write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ["user1", "user2", "user3"].include? current_user.name
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's rails, then `.in?` method is available.

```
if current_user.name.in?(['user1', 'user2', 'user3'])
```

For vanilla ruby use `.include?`

```
if %w[user1 user2 user3].include?(current_user.name)
```

Comment: It should be `current_user.name.in?(['user1', 'user2', 'user3'])`. Note: `[]` around. But, I prefer the Ruby-way. :)

Comment: Guys, do try this in rails console :)

Comment: I just did. Did you try? :)

Comment: [1] pry(main)> 1.in?(1, 2, 3)
=> true

Comment: `'user1'.in?('user1', 'user2', 'user3')
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)`

Comment: Using Rails 4.1.1. :)

Comment: It was working fine, I tried it now `pry(main)> ('a').in?('a','b','c')
=> true`

Comment: I'm on 3.2.3. Maybe they removed it later. A pity.

Comment: @RSB : I am using Ruby 2.1, Rails 4.1.1. I get this: `('user1').in?('user1', 'user2', 'user3').. ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)` Not sure how it worked for you though. Which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Uh, similar to Sergio, he's right then. I guess they removed this in later version.